# Freshly cloned hg repository shows files as modified (Windows)

Tags: mercurial, clone

I've freshly cloned a Hg repository on Windows XP and `hg status` reports a lot of (all?) files as `M`odified. What could be the reason?

```
E:\myprojects\myproject>hg summary
parent: 206:03856faec803 tip
 latest commit message
branch: default
commit: 78 modified
update: (current)
```

Even after having performed `hg revert --all --no-backup`, `hg diff --git` reports:

```
diff --git a/path/to/file1 b/path/to/file1
--- a/path/to/file1
+++ b/path/to/file1
@@ -1,332 +1,332 @@
-line1
-line2
...
-line332
+line1
+line2
...
+line332
diff --git a/path/to/file2 b/path/to/file2
--- a/path/to/file2
+++ b/path/to/file2
@@ -1,231 +1,231 @@
...
 line231
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: Can you show the result of `hg status`. At least a part of the output

Comment: Could you copy paste your findings exactly (clone command, hg status command, and the result of it ...)?

Comment: There is really nothing fancy. Just all files are showing up with a leading `M` directly after the clone (`hg clone ssh://user@server:<port>/repository.hg E:\myproject`) when invoking `hg status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `hg revert` isn't able to restore a clean working directory, this most likely means that the repository doesn't contain the files in *canonical* form, but `hg status` gets them into canonical form before comparing against the repository contents. Usually this happens when *eol*-extension is turned on, but the repository contains files with CRLF. To be sure, turn *eol*-extension temporarily off and check whether the files are still modified. If so:

(1) turn it on again and commit the changes, so they will be in canonical form in the repository, too.

(2) make sure that other users accessing your repository have *eol*-extension turned on, otherwise this will be a never ending game :)

Comment: Yes, the files are not reported as modified, if I turn off the eol-extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try `hg diff --git` that will shows you what Mercurial thinks is modified about the files.  My guess is the execute bit permission.

Comment: When the whole repo is modified without reason my suspicion usually falls on EOLs. However, hard to say in this case ... so few known things.

Comment: yeah, mercurial mostly doesn't muck w/ line endings, but there are extensions that will and editors that will too. If it really is _everything_ my money is on file permissions.

Comment: then @idigas is probably right and something (likely not Mercurial) messed up you line endings.  Can you put the out out of `hg summary` up into the question?

Comment: OK, I've added the output of `hg summary`. Is there something like a `git reset --hard` for Hg?

Comment: `git reset --hard` is `hg revert --all --no-backup` (found at http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GitConcepts ).  What does the output of `hg diff --git` look like?  At least a few short files worth.

Comment: OK, added output of `hg diff --git`.

Comment: That sure really looks like line endings.  Thanks for being a sport about this.  Can you provide the output of both `hg showconfig | grep extensions` and `hg showconfig | grep hook` please?

Comment: `grep` is not available on Windows. The output shows, among others, following lines `extensions.eol=` and `hooks.preupdate.eol=<function preupdate at 0x012F6970>`.

Comment: Yes, those are your problem.  Someone has configured those for your system and you want to make them stop. `hg showconfig --debug` will show you what file those are enabled in (possibly system wide by your admin).  Disable them and use an editor that respects line endings of either sort (Windows has many of those, but notepad.exe isn't one of them).